# siunitx: How to hide a part of a number

Tags: siunitx

I want to suppress a number in a `\SI`-command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,textcomp}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\begin{document}
current output: (\SI{{}e9}{\per\litre}) %

current output: (\SI{1e9}{\per\litre}) %

wanted output:  (\texttimes~10\textsuperscript{9}/l)

\sisetup{exponent-product = \cdot}

current output: (\SI{{}e9}{\per\litre}) %

current output: (\SI{1e9}{\per\litre}) %

wanted output:  ($\cdot$~10\textsuperscript{9}/l)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way to do it? I don't want to hard code with `\texttimes` as I don't know if the style of exponent-product will change in the future.

Comment: Would `(\si{{}\times 10^9\per\litre})` be acceptable? In effect, this method moves the `\times 10^9` part from the numbers-part to the units-part of the full expression.

Comment: @Mico: I had a similar idea, but what's the advantage of `\si` then? I think, Ulrike is after an automated typesetting of `x some power of ten` using the `siunitx` tools

Comment: @Mico: `\times` has the same problem then `\texttimes`: It doesn't change with changes of the exponent style through `\sisetup`. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can type `\SI{e9}{…}` instead of `\SI{{}e9}{…}`, i.e. no need for the empty group.

Comment: Log a feature request with a good example of a use case from the published literature :-)

Comment: Do you want to drop any mantissa or just unity (1) mantissa?

Comment: @HenriMenke I want the shown output from a more or less "sane", semantic input.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst there is no built in mechanism for 'suppress part of a number' in general, one can (ab)use `exponent-base` here, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,textcomp}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,}
\begin{document}
current output: (\SI{e9}{\per\litre}) %

wanted output:  (\texttimes~10\textsuperscript{9}/l)

\sisetup{exponent-base = \ensuremath{\mathrel{\times}10}}
current output: (\SI{e9}{\per\litre}) %

\end{document}
```

Of course, whether this approach is applicable or not depends on your requirements: it will work well in a case where you have grouping, for example.

Comment: BTW, assuming the parenthetic term here is for something like a table header, I'm sure you know it is formally a division so just `(10^{9}/l)` or similar is correct.

Comment: How about `\num[explicit-sign=\@gobble]{1e9}` (with `\makeatletter`)? Hacky, but currently works output-wise... (I think the idea was to use `\times` the same way as `siunitx` does, and not to repeat the definition.)

Comment: @krlmlr Only works if there is exactly one token following

Comment: This still assumes that I know the current output of exponent-product. I'm more looking foe something like `\printcurrentexponentproductpart\si{e9}{\per\litre}`. So where is the symbol and the space stored? (I know that isn't standard output, but as it is wanted ...)